# How to add a synonym for a concept in an existing ontology?

Tags: rdf, owl, ontology, rdfs

Given an existing ontology, how can I add an alternative label for a concept? In particular, I'm trying to add synonyms for ChEBI concepts.
Example: here is the ChEBI class for Herbicide. We can see some synonyms (like herbizid). I could just go and add copy/paste that to add my own synonym, but that won't be extending the ontology, just modifying the original one.

```
<owl:Class rdf:about="http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/CHEBI_24527">
        <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/CHEBI_25944"/>
        <obo:IAO_0000115 rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">A substance used to destroy plant pests.</obo:IAO_0000115>
        <oboInOwl:hasDbXref rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">Wikipedia:Herbicide</oboInOwl:hasDbXref>
        <oboInOwl:hasOBONamespace rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">chebi_ontology</oboInOwl:hasOBONamespace>
        <oboInOwl:hasRelatedSynonym rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">Herbizid</oboInOwl:hasRelatedSynonym>
        <oboInOwl:hasRelatedSynonym rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">Unkrautbekaempfungsmittel</oboInOwl:hasRelatedSynonym>
        <oboInOwl:hasRelatedSynonym rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">Unkrautvertilgungsmittel</oboInOwl:hasRelatedSynonym>
        <oboInOwl:hasRelatedSynonym rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">Wildkrautbekaempfungsmittel</oboInOwl:hasRelatedSynonym>
        <oboInOwl:hasRelatedSynonym rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">herbicides</oboInOwl:hasRelatedSynonym>
        <oboInOwl:id rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">CHEBI:24527</oboInOwl:id>
        <oboInOwl:inSubset rdf:resource="http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/chebi#3_STAR"/>
        <rdfs:label rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">herbicide</rdfs:label>
    </owl:Class>
```

Comment: I don't fully get what you mean by extending vs modifying. One of the most common approaches for adding labels is to use `skos:altLabel`. Generally look at SKOS ontology. You can create a file with these labels and just import it to the main ontology as and when you need it and keep the main file intact.

Comment: in addition to using existing vocabularies like SKOS you can always use your own ... in the end the question is if tools and people are able to "understand" the property you added. Moreover, you can also as many labels as you want via `rdfs:label`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This really comes down to whether the extension will only be used privately (i.e., by yourself or the organization you work for) or whether the extension has value for the community in general.

In the private case you can create your own ontology that imports chebi and then you can add the extensions you want to your ontology. Importing chebi will allow you to get access to newer releases of chebi whereas maintaining your own copy of chebi will cause you to be stuck with that version of chebi.

In the general case it is best to open an issue in the [issue tracker](https://github.com/ebi-chebi/ChEBI/issues) of chebi. Further, chebi allows you to become a user which seems to allow you to [submit](https://www.ebi.ac.uk/chebi/submission/login) changes. This way your changes (once accepted) will benefit the community in general.